# removed style from CKEditor to SQL

Tags: sql, tags, ckeditor, styles

Yo,

so, I'm using CKEditor to add contents but, when I need to save these in my DB, 'style' attributes are removed and replaced by [removed] tags.

Here, a short example with my CKEditor content :

```
<h2 style="font-style:italic;"><span style="color:#FF0000">hello I need info</span></h2>
```

which is replaced in my DB by

```
<h2 [removed]:italic;"><span [removed]>hello I need info</span></h2>
```

and my PHP query looks like :

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE `menu` SET content = "'.$this->input->post('textareaCK').'"');
```

(ps: I'm using CodeIgniter)

I found solutions on SO or others forums but nothing seems to be fine ... So, I handed over all the files to the original except config.js which looks like :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;
};
```

I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace config.php

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

Or

```
$this->input->post('name' , FALSE);
```

try

Comment: My god. Works fine so easily ! Thanks you ! :)